# How do I change 2 random variables out of 4?

Tags: python, variables, random, replace

I need to change the value of two random variables out of four to '—'. How do I do it with maximum effectiveness and readability?
Code below is crap just for reference.

```
from random import choice
a = 10
b = 18
c = 15
d = 92

choice(a, b, c, d) = '—'
choice(a, b, c, d) = '—'

print(a, b, c, d)

>>> 12 — — 92
>>> — 19 — 92
>>> 10 18 — —
```

I've tried ***choice(a, b, c, d) = '—'*** but ofc it didn't work. There's probably a solution using list functions and methods but it's complicated and almost impossible to read, so I'm searching for an easier solution.

Comment: Is there a reason for using four separate variables instead of a `list` of four numbers?

Comment: If you need to access the abcd variables individually by name still, then it seems like storing them in a `dict` would let you do that without affecting readability much, as well as randomly select ones to modify. Without knowing the context for this, though, it's hard to say if that would be any more preferable or readable than using a list.

Comment: @Roman check if my solution works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into consideration that you need to create 4 separate variables. Here's what you can do:

```
from random import sample
a = 10
b = 18
c = 15
d = 92
for i in sample(['a','b','c','d'], k=2):
    exec(f"{i} = '-'")
print(a,b,c,d)
```

Using `sample` ensures non-repeating values.
However, this approach is not recommended but is just provided to help you understand the problem better. I recommend using a list or dictionary as stated by other fellow developers.

Comment: I'm late already but thank you so much! exec() function seems to be useful in plenty of other cases! @The Myth

Comment: @Roman Yes, but I'd still recommend you to not use it. It's a possible approach but won't be good for high-end programs. Just go with native methods such as dicts for complex data structures.

Answer (score 1):

Variable names are not available when you run your code, so you cannot change a "random variable". Instead, I recommend that you use a list or a dictionary. Then you can choose a random element from the list or a random key from the dictionary.

Comment: Well, they could change it using `exec()`

Comment: Technically you can access variables by name via `locals` e.g. `locals()['a']` though this is not usually a good idea...

Comment: @TheMyth Sure, but I don't want to teach the evils of `exec()` so I just pretend it doesn't exist.

Comment: @match Yes, I am telling a white lie here for the sake of promoting good programming practices.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice true that but let's just explain them why it's bad.

Answer (score 1):

Given the constraint of four named variables, I might do:

```
from random import sample
a = 10
b = 18
c = 15
d = 92

v = sample("abcd", 2)
if "a" in v:
    a = "_"
if "b" in v:
    b = "_"
if "c" in v:
    c = "_"
if "d" in v:
    d = "_"

print(a, b, c, d)
```

This is readable, but it's also extremely repetitive.  It's much easier to do it if there aren't four individual variables:

```
from random import sample
nums = {
    "a": 10,
    "b": 18,
    "c": 15,
    "d": 92,
}

for v in sample(nums, 2):
    nums[v] = "_"

print(*nums.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

data = [10, 18, 15, 92]

already_changed = []
for i in range(2): # change 2 to however many numbers you want to change

    index=random.randint(0,len(data)-1) # randomly select an index to change
    while index in already_changed: # makes sure not to change the same index
        index = random.randint(0, len(data) - 1)

    data[index] = "_" 

print(data)
```

Comment: If the two calls to `randint` happen to return the same, then only one element will be changed to `_`

Comment: Cool - another way would be to use `random.sample(range(len(data)), k=2)` to pick 2 indexes (guaranteed to be different) in one operation.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do `choice(a, b, c, d) = '-'` because choice is not a variable and can therefore not be assigned.

You should store the variables in a list then replace random elements with your string. That could be done like so:

```py
from random import randint

a = 10
b = 18
c = 15
d = 92

replacement = "--"
nums = [a, b, c, d]

while nums.count(replacement) < 2:
    # create random index
    index = randint(0, len(nums)-1)
    # replace value at index with the replacement
    nums[index] = replacement

print(*nums) # print each element in the list
```

However, be aware that this code doesnt change the values of a, b, c, d. If you want that, you need to reset the variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by picking any two indices from a list of items at random, and replacing the element at that index position with `_`:

```
import random

x = [10,18,15,92]

for i in random.sample(range(len(x)), 2):
    x[i] = '_'

print(x)
```